# cmake ignoring CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX inside CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I have a small project with a very simple CMakeLists.txt file.  At the bottom of this file, I have the following lines:

```
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  /opt/myprod)
message (STATUS "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
install (TARGETS myprod DESTINATION bin)
```

However, when I run:

```
sudo make install
```

I get the following:

```
[100%] Built target myprod
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/bin/myprod
-- Up-to-date: /usr/bin/myprod
```

cmake always puts my executable under **/usr/bin** when it should be under **/opt/myprod/bin**.
And, yes, the last line is always repeated.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Using cmake 3.20.3 on Fedora 34.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue cannot be reproduced with the level of detail you've given:

File `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(myprod)

add_executable(myprod main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/myprod)
message (STATUS "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
install (TARGETS myprod DESTINATION bin)
```

File `main.cpp`

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

Commands:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
...
$ cmake --build build/
$ sudo cmake --build build/ --target install
[sudo] password for alex:
[0/1] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /opt/myprod/bin/myprod
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/myprod/
```

So as you can see, `/opt/myprod` survived to the final output.

---

The `install()` command is responsible for generating the `cmake_install.cmake` script in the build directory. As far as I know, the very first one reads `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, so you must have another call to `install()` in your project that you aren't showing us.

Furthermore, you should not set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` inside the `CMakeLists.txt`; it is *designed* to be set externally as a cache variable. Hard-coding it is bad because someone else might wish to install your project to a different location besides `/opt`. Maybe they're on a different operating system or Linux distribution. Maybe even *your* whims change. In any case, one shouldn't need to edit a file to change the install prefix.

Since you're using CMake 3.20, I *strongly* encourage you to move such settings to [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).

Comment: You are correct, Alex.  There was indeed another install() in another CMakeLists.txt file that I was not aware of.  Thank you for your help.